# Centrality of Gaussian distribution for LWE error

Tags: number-theory, lwe, ring-lwe, computational-complexity-theory

Consider the LWE problem.

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, $x$ is an $n \times 1$ vector, $u$ is a $m \times 1$ vector, and $e$ is sampled from a Gaussian distribution.

We are given either $Ax + e ~~(mod~q)$ or $u ~(mod~q)$ the conjecture being that it is difficult to distinguish between these samples in polynomial time, with high probability over the choice of $A$, $x$, $u$ and $e$ (for appropriate choices of $m$ and $q$.)

I wanted to ask about the centrality of the Gaussian distribution while considering the security of LWE.

Is LWE hard if $e$ is sampled from other distributions — like the uniform distribution or the exponential distribution?

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/939.pdf
look at the page 40
"Note that this original error e can come from any distribution, as long as it is relatively
short."

Comment: That quote is about the correctness of a procedure for generating fresh LWE samples from some given ones. It’s not about the security of LWE with alternative error distributions.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert Are there references on the correctness of LWE with alternative other distributions?